# After first onClick, animation no longer plays in FF 23, IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, animation

I'm trying to write a basic content slider using css and javascript.  There is one php variable, but that sets the width.

While in Chrome, everything works correctly.  You click left as many times as you want and each time it shows the animation correctly.  You click right it moves right correctly.  When you switch to Firefox 23 or IE 10, it stops working right.

The best way I can explain it, you click left, it shows the animation.  You click left again, and every time you click left after, the timeout finally changes the slide.  No animation.  Oddly enough, at anytime you click the right button, it shows the correct animation the first time, and then again, the time out changes the slide, no animation.  You can go back and forth.  Slide 1 to slide 2, shows animation.  Slide 2 to slide 1, shows the animation.

It's like there is one thing I'm missing.  Switching from one direction to the other is the key.  It is "resetting" something... ?

Thanks for any help, the following is code, locations and examples.

You can see it live at:
http://musicwhynot.com/slide.php
This is working in chrome.  But Fire fox and IE fail.

jsfiddle.  It doesn't work in any browser and this is the first time I've used it, but at least this breaks the code up for you.  This is of course minus any PHP : http://jsfiddle.net/769we/

And the actual code:

```
<?php $slide_width=800; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
    .sliding_div    {
        width:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;
        position:relative;

        animation-name: right-to-left;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease; 
        animation-delay: 0s;           
        animation-iteration-count: 1;  
        animation-play-state:paused;
        backface-visibility: hidden;

        -moz-animation-name: right-to-left;
        -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease; 
        -moz-animation-delay: 0s;           
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;  
        -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

        -webkit-animation-name: right-to-left;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; 
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;           
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;  
        -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    @keyframes right-to-left {
        from {left:0px;}
        to {left:-<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes right-to-left {
        from {left:0px;}
        to {left:-<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes right-to-left {
        from {left:0px;}
        to {left:-<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;}
    }


    @keyframes left-to-right {
        from {left:0px;}
        to {left:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes left-to-right {
        from {left:0px;}
        to {left:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes left-to-right {
        from {left:0px;}
        to {left:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;}
    }
</style>


</head>

<body style="background-color:grey;" onload="do_load();">
<center>

    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="move_last_slide();" value="<-" />
    <input type="button" onclick="move_next_slide();" value="->" /><br />
    <span id="output"></span>
    <br /><br />


    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;height:400px;background-color:white;">
        <div class="sliding_div" id="my-div">
            <div id="div0" style="width:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;height:400px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;display:inline-block;opacity:1;">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1"><tr><td align="center" valign="middle">0</td></tr></table>
            </div>

            <div id="div1" style="width:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;height:400px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;display:inline-block;opacity:0;">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1"><tr><td align="center" valign="middle">1</td></tr></table>
            </div>

            <div id="div2" style="width:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;height:400px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;display:inline-block;opacity:0;">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1"><tr><td align="center" valign="middle">2</td></tr></table>
            </div>

            <div id="div3" style="width:<?php echo $slide_width; ?>px;height:400px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;display:inline-block;opacity:0;">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1"><tr><td align="center" valign="middle">3</td></tr></table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</center>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var num_slides=3; // INCLUDES 0!

    var cur_slide=0;

    var last_slide;
    var next_slide;

    var in_motion=0;

    var slide_width = <?php echo $slide_width; ?>;

    function do_load() {
        change_slide(0)
    };

    function change_slide(new_slide_num) {
        cur_slide = new_slide_num;

        if ( cur_slide < 0 ) { cur_slide=num_slides; }
        if ( cur_slide > num_slides ) { cur_slide = 0; }


        last_slide = cur_slide - 1;
        if ( last_slide < 0 ) { last_slide=num_slides; }


        next_slide = cur_slide + 1;
        if ( next_slide > num_slides ) { next_slide = 0;    }

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "cur_slide = " + cur_slide + ", num_slides = " + num_slides + ", next_slide = " + next_slide + ", last_slide = " + last_slide;
    };


    function move_next_slide() {
        if (in_motion==0) {

        for (var i=0;i<=num_slides;i++) { 
            document.getElementById("div" + i).style.opacity="0";
        }

            document.getElementById("div" + cur_slide).style.opacity="1";
            document.getElementById("div" + cur_slide).style.left = ("0px");

            document.getElementById("div" + next_slide).style.opacity="1";
            document.getElementById("div" + next_slide).style.left = (slide_width + "px");

            cur_slide++;
            change_slide(cur_slide);

            in_motion=1;

            document.getElementById("my-div").classList.remove("sliding_div");
            document.getElementById("my-div").offsetWidth = document.getElementById("my-div").offsetWidth;
            document.getElementById("my-div").classList.add("sliding_div");

            document.getElementById("my-div").style.webkitAnimationName="right-to-left";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.mozAnimationName="right-to-left";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.animationName="right-to-left";

            document.getElementById("my-div").style.animationPlayState="running";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.mozAnimationPlayState="running";

            setTimeout("move_done()", 1000);
        }
    };

    function move_last_slide() {
        if (in_motion==0) {

        for (var i=0;i<=num_slides;i++) { 
            document.getElementById("div" + i).style.opacity="0";
        }

            document.getElementById("div" + cur_slide).style.opacity="1";
            document.getElementById("div" + cur_slide).style.left = ("0px");

            document.getElementById("div" + last_slide).style.opacity="1";
            document.getElementById("div" + last_slide).style.left = "-" + slide_width + "px";

            cur_slide--;
            change_slide(cur_slide);

            in_motion=1;


            document.getElementById("my-div").classList.remove("sliding_div");
            document.getElementById("my-div").offsetWidth = document.getElementById("my-div").offsetWidth;
            document.getElementById("my-div").classList.add("sliding_div");

            document.getElementById("my-div").style.webkitAnimationName="left-to-right";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.mozAnimationName="left-to-right";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.animationName="left-to-right";

            document.getElementById("my-div").style.animationPlayState="running";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
            document.getElementById("my-div").style.mozAnimationPlayState="running";

            setTimeout("move_done()", 1000);
        }
    };


    function move_done() {

        for (var i=0;i<=num_slides;i++) { 
            document.getElementById("div" + i).style.opacity="0";
        }

        document.getElementById("div" + cur_slide).style.opacity="1";
        document.getElementById("div" + cur_slide).style.left = "0px";

        in_motion="0";
    };

</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, the counters are working.... hmmm

Comment: can you use jquery????

Comment: yeah, the counters work great.  And the timeout function is being called!  I am trying to avoid using any extra libraries.  Looking for pure as possible.  Thanks